# Can't insert integer type to DB

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm having trouble using integers in DB. I have a SQLiteOpenHelper here I create

DBAdapter:

```
public static final String KEY_ROWID="id";
public static final String KEY_EXR="name";
public static final String KEY_WGHT="weight";
public static final String KEY_REP="repetition";
public static final String KEY_DATE="duedate";
final static String[] columns = {KEY_ROWID, KEY_EXR, KEY_WGHT, KEY_REP};



   final static String DATABASE_NAME = "ExerciseDB";
final static String DATABASE_TABLE = "exercisetb";
final static int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;


//DBAdapter için Loglar

private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";



private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
        "create table if not exists exercisetb (id integer primary key autoincrement, "
                + "name VARCHAR not null, weight VARCHAR not null, repetition integer not null);";
```

Inserting:

```
  public long insertRecord() {


            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

            values.put(DBAdapter.KEY_EXR, name.toString());

            values.put(DBAdapter.KEY_WGHT, weight.toString();

            values.put(DBAdapter.KEY_REP, Integer.parseInt(repetition.toString()));
            values.clear();

            return mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase().insert(DBAdapter.DATABASE_NAME, null, values);

        }
```

EDIT: 
I added insertRecord() to show which step occurs problem:

```
 public long insertRecord() {


            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

            values.put(DBAdapter.KEY_EXR, name.toString());
            Log.i(TAG,"Name field assign.");

            values.put(DBAdapter.KEY_WGHT, Integer.parseInt(weight.toString()));
            Log.i(TAG,"weight assisgn.");
            values.put(DBAdapter.KEY_REP, Integer.parseInt(repetition.toString()));
            Log.i(TAG,"repetition field assign.");
            values.clear();

            return mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase().insert(DBAdapter.DATABASE_NAME, null, values);

        }
```

Log output after I try to insert:

```
04-07 15:23:25.217    3442-3442/com.example.alperen.exercisem I/addnew﹕ OnClick'e girildi
04-07 15:23:25.217    3442-3442/com.example.alperen.exercisem I/addnew﹕ Name field assign.
04-07 15:23:25.217    3442-3442/com.example.alperen.exercisem I/addnew﹕ weight assisgn.
04-07 15:23:25.217    3442-3442/com.example.alperen.exercisem D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
04-07 15:23:25.217    3442-3442/com.example.alperen.exercisem W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x430ef140)
04-07 15:23:25.227    3442-3442/com.example.alperen.exercisem E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.alperen.exercisem, PID: 3442
    java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "android.widget.EditText{21d1d000 VFED..CL .F...... 0,166-720,249 #7f080043 app:id/repetition}"
            at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:137)
            at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:374)
            at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:365)
            at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:331)
            at com.example.alperen.exercisem.Addnew$1.insertRecord(Addnew.java:69)
```

The problem occurs on last variable. We can put KEY_EXR; KEY_WGHT but not KEY_REP. If I change KEY_REP column to VARCHAR only then I can add data to that line. I 'm probably making mistake during table create.

Comment: repetition INTEGER not null

Comment: Which **integer** are you trying to insert?

Comment: do you get an error? what is the result?

Comment: If you use "repetition integer not null" you have to declare DEFAULT like `default 0`. Im wondering how do you actually created DB this way with no exception. Also you are clearing all the inserting values right before inserting (at `values.clear();`) that way you wont insert anything at all including KEY_EXR and KEY_WGHT. Also try to values.put(DBAdapter.KEY_REP, 0xDEAD); to see it adds an integer at all (I mean no Integer Parse exception happens)

Comment: I'm doing clearing values in the end now. Still having problem.
Changed the method like this :
private void insertRecord() {
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(DBAdapter.KEY_EXR, name.toString());
                

            values.put(DBAdapter.KEY_WGHT, weight.toString());
 values.put(DBAdapter.KEY_REP,Integer.parseInt(repetition.toString()));
          


                long id= mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase().insert(DBAdapter.DATABASE_NAME, null, values);
                values.clear();
            }

Comment: You are still ignoring my advice to put a constant to an KEY_REP, like `values.put(DBAdapter.KEY_REP, 505)` to test. Also you has to recreate DB using `default`.

Comment: values.put(DBAdapter.KEY_REP, 505) this works.
 I 'm making a DBAdapter object in this activity where I insert records. Doing it on onCreate(). I'm not sure what do you mean by recreating DB by using default..

Comment: `...repetition integer not null default 0`

Comment: >values.put(DBAdapter.KEY_REP, 505) this works" - so it not a SQLite issue. Its about a vlaue you pass via `values`. Like `Integer.parseInt(repetition.toString())` does not return real int but probably null instead. Thats why `VARCHAR` works.

Answer (score 0):

For not null fields, specify Default values also.
Also, as per crash report, there is number format exception. Check Integer.parseInt(repetition.toString()), quite possible repetition is not numeric value.

Answer (score -1):

please comment line in your insertRecord() methode :

//values.clear();

because its clear your values from  values list, and it will not update new row in your table.